# WKWebView bugged header for evaluateJavaScript

Tags: ios, xcode, autocomplete, wkwebview

I'm trying to call the "evaluateJavaScript" method provided by WKWebView.  When I use autocompletion in XCode, the resulting code doesn't compile and if I jump to the declaration of the method it seems like the method definition is bad.

From the doc (found at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript?language=objc)

```
- (void)evaluateJavaScript:(NSString *)javaScriptString 
         completionHandler:(void (^)(id, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

From the code, if you "Jump to definition"

```
  - (void)evaluateJavaScript:(NSString *)javaScriptString completionHandler:(void (^ _Nullable)(_Nullable id, NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler;
```

Notice that in both the docs and "live" header, the first parameter to the completion handler seems incomplete: it specifies "id" but no parameter name such as "result".  I was expecting to see a parameter list that looked something like (id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error)

This is such a weird screw up that I'm questioning if there is some new parameter shorthand I'm unaware of for "id"?  Or did Apple really screw up the auto-complete header definition?

I'm using XCode version 12.0

Comment: Filed a bug on this via Apple's feedback assistant.